# StartActivity is undefined for the type?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that this question has been already asked, but the existing answers do not work for me.

Here is my code :

```
   public class OrganizatorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_organizator);

        Button newText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newText);

        newText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(OrganizatorActivity.this, NewnoteActivity.class);
                OrganizatorActivity.this.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error : The method `StartActivity(Intent)` is undefined for the type `OrganizatorActivity`

I tried this too :

```
StartActivity(intent);
```

**Error** : The method `StartActivity(Intent)` is undefined for the type new `View.OnClickListener(){}`

And this doesn't work either :

```
getApplicationContext().StartActivity(intent);
```

**Error** : The method `StartActivity(Intent)` is undefined for the type `Context`

My API level is 8, Android 2.2.

`OrganizatorActivity` is my main activity and `NewnoteActivity` is the activity i want to open with the intent ( called from button click ).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StartActivity should be startActivity. Lowercase 's'. Also, as a hind thought, you don't really need `OrganizatorActivity.this`. This scope is implied. Just placing `startActivity(Intent)` would work.

Comment: I don't know how I missed the lowercase 's', but now it's OK. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public class OrganizatorActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_organizator);

    Button newText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newText);

    final Context context = this; 
    newText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(OrganizatorActivity.this, NewnoteActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `startActivity(intent)` or `context.startActivity(intent)` instead of `StartActivity(intent)`.
(Mind the first letter, it isn't capitilized).

For more: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)